# Replace double slashes with single slash and four slashes with two slashes

Tags: java, string, url

I have below URL:

```
http:////www.test.com//test
```

I want to replace double slashes with single slash and four slashes with two slashes, that is, output is like:

```
http://www.test.com/test
```

Comment: [`.replace("//", "/")`](http://ideone.com/G9oDVS) works. Do not forget to assign to a variable if you plan to use it further (`s = s.replace("//", "/");`)

Answer (score 0):

```
String sURL="http:////www.test.com//test";
sURL=sURL.replace("////","/x/x/x/x");
sURL=sURL.replace("//","/");
sURL=sURL.replace("/x/x/x/x","//");
```

`/x/x/x/x` is just an arbitrary string that you are guaranteed not to encounter naturally inside the URL. It "hides" the four slashes from being replaced by `sURL.replace("//","/");`

You could try just:

```
String sURL="http:////www.test.com//test";
sURL=sURL.replace("//","/");
```

but I don't know if that will turn all four slashes into a single one and I don't have handy platform to test.

Edit: Added `sURL=` to make it work properly "as is" rather than an example. Also I am seeing conflicting posts regarding replace (some posts have it working with strings while others just with single characters) and I don't have a test platform so `replace` may need to be `replaceAll`

Comment: @PrestonM: It runs just fine in the language that the question is actually tagged for (Java) and not for the language you answered for (JavaScript). Some elementary fact checking would not hurt before going around down voting everything.

Answer (score -1):

[myString.replace("//", "/");](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) should work

Answer (score -1):

```
String s1 = "http:////www.test.com//test.";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("//", "/");
```

The method replaceAll works on regular expressions, but a simplest regex is just the string itself - here "//".

Comment: try it. output is http:/www.test.com/test

Comment: Please undo the downvote - I tested and the output is correct.

Comment: works fine on Java 8 on Linux. I have just checked again.